# Elasticsearch 6.5.0 accepts new field as keyword while 6.5.4 accepts new field as long

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field meta.http.status_code which is not set in the default mapping, and in reality it can be string or number. In the past the field was automatically generated in Elasticsearch 6.5.0 and was set to 'Keyword' but after upgrading to 6.5.4, it becomes 'Long'. This because problematic because when it was 'Keyword' it can accept both string and number but now it only accepts number. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test this on the mentioned two versions, but I strongly feel that its not the versions that is leading to different behaviour. The reason would be the type of non null data getting indexed for the first time when the field doesn't exist. When elasticsearch finds a new field which doesn't exist in the mapping, it tries to identify the best datatype for the field based on the value of the field coming for the first time. So for e.g.:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
   "new_field": "ID123"
}
```

For the above, `new_field` will be identified as `text` field and elastic will define its type as `text` and also create an additional sub field with type as `keyword`.

Now if the first document with the `new_field` comes as below:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
   "new_field": "123"
}
```

In this case the `new_field` data type will be determined as `double` since the input value is numeric.

So it is the ***first document having the new field with a non null value*** that matters and determines the data type for this new field.

The above functionality is called dynamic mapping. You can read more on it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/dynamic-field-mapping.html).

Comment: I understand this would be how it works normally. Perhaps there is a setting somewhere I can force new field to be mapped as keyword. I would have noticed the difference long ago if meta.http.status_code was mapped as long instead of keyword.